# chartjs push array to label not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Dynamically updating a chartjs chart and creating the labels in an array format (["A","B","C"]). However chartjs doesn't accept a push of the label array unless it is in the format "A","B","C" (without brackets). Anyone else experience this or have I misunderstood? Se code below. Produces this [image]

Instead of this (ok when adding labels as chart.data.labels.push("A","B","C","D")
[image]

```
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("element"), {
        type: 'bar',
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
    //PUSH DATA TO GRAPH. 
        var verserier = [];
        var veromslperserie = [];
        var stat = seriestat(); //function to retrieve data for labels
        $.each(stat, function(i, item) {
            verserier.push(i);
            veromslperserie.push(item["omsl"]);
        });
        chart.data.labels.push(verserier); //error occurs here
        chart.data.datasets.push({
                label: "Omsl",
                data: veromslperserie,
                backgroundColor: colorarray,
        });
        chart.update();
```

Comment: One solution is of course to push each iteration but just strange a total array can't be pushed the same way as for the dataset itself. chartomslperserie.data.labels.push(i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push outside of the loop you are actually pushing verserier into position [n], which in this case is 0.

If you do not add values again you can do

```
chart.data.labels = verserier
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the explanation of the "why", but here's a workaround :

```
var data_array = new Array();

// This doesn't work (but with no error on my side, appart from visually wrong labels)
myChart.data.labels.push(data_array);

// But this works
for(i=0;i<data_array.length;i++)
{
    myChart.data.labels.push(data_array[i]);
}
```